# Put a legend into GEE map

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

How can I add a legend to my own script? I'm new in GEE's JavaScript environment.

I attached my script right here:

```
//  Palette with the colors
var palette = ('FF0000', '22ff00', '00BA08','006304');

exports.splitt=function(images){var colorizedVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 4.0,
  palette: palette,
};

// Create the left map, and have it display layer 0.
var leftMap = ui.Map();
leftMap.add(createLegend())
leftMap.setControlVisibility(true);
var leftSelector = addLayerSelector(leftMap, 0, 'top-left');
//Map.addLayer(leftMap, viz);

// Create the right map, and have it display layer 1.
var rightMap = ui.Map();
rightMap.add(createLegend())
rightMap.setControlVisibility(true);
var rightSelector = addLayerSelector(rightMap, 1, 'top-right');

// Adds a layer selection widget to the given map, to allow users to change
// which image is displayed in the associated map.
function addLayerSelector(mapToChange, defaultValue, position) {
  var label = ui.Label('Choose an image to visualize');

  // This function changes the given map to show the selected image.
  function updateMap(selection) {
    mapToChange.layers().set(0, ui.Map.Layer(images[selection],colorizedVis));
  }

  // Configure a selection dropdown to allow the user to choose between images,
  // and set the map to update when a user makes a selection.
  var select = ui.Select({items: Object.keys(images), onChange: updateMap});
  select.setValue(Object.keys(images)[defaultValue], true);

  var controlPanel =
      ui.Panel({widgets: [label, select, ], style: {position: position}});
  mapToChange.add(controlPanel);
}
  
//create the first panel 
function createLegend() {
   // set position of panel
var legend = ui.Panel({
  style: {
    position: 'bottom-left',
    padding: '8px 15px'
  }
});

// Create legend title
var legendTitle = ui.Label({
  value: 'My Legend',
  style: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: '18px',
    margin: '0 0 4px 0',
    padding: '0'
    }
});

// Add the title to the panel
legend.add(legendTitle);
    
// Creates and styles 1 row of the legend.
var makeRow = function(color, name) {
      
      // Create the label that is actually the colored box.
      var colorBox = ui.Label({
        style: {
          backgroundColor: '#' + color,
          
          // Use padding to give the box height and width.
          padding: '8px',
          margin: '0 0 4px 0'
        }
      });
      
      // Create the label filled with the description text.
      var description = ui.Label({
        value: name,
        style: {margin: '0 0 4px 6px'}
      });
      
      // return the panel
      return ui.Panel({
        widgets: [colorBox, description],
        layout: ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal')
      });
};

//  Palette with the colors
//var palette =['FF0000', '22ff00', '00BA08','006304'];

// name of the legend
var names = ['Red','Green','Blue','blue'];

// Add color and and names
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  return legend.add(makeRow(palette[i], names[i]));
  }  
  
legend.add(makeRow);

// add legend to map (alternatively you can also print the legend to the console)  
//Map.add(legend);  

  return legend
}

// Create a SplitPanel to hold the adjacent, linked maps.
var splitPanel = ui.SplitPanel({
  firstPanel: leftMap,
  secondPanel: rightMap,
  wipe: true,
  style: {stretch: 'both'}
});

// Set the SplitPanel as the only thing in the UI root.
ui.root.widgets().reset([splitPanel]);
var linker = ui.Map.Linker([leftMap, rightMap]);
leftMap.setCenter(13.1, 37.72604, 12);
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code: [Code link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f8974c85a9ee57373538d0bdcb94efb8)

```
// set position of panel
var legend = ui.Panel({
  style: {
    position: 'bottom-left',
    padding: '8px 15px'
  }
});

// Create legend title
var legendTitle = ui.Label({
  value: 'My Legend',
  style: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: '18px',
    margin: '0 0 4px 0',
    padding: '0'
    }
});

// Add the title to the panel
legend.add(legendTitle);
    
// Creates and styles 1 row of the legend.
var makeRow = function(color, name) {
      
      // Create the label that is actually the colored box.
      var colorBox = ui.Label({
        style: {
          backgroundColor: '#' + color,
          // Use padding to give the box height and width.
          padding: '8px',
          margin: '0 0 4px 0'
        }
      });
      
      // Create the label filled with the description text.
      var description = ui.Label({
        value: name,
        style: {margin: '0 0 4px 6px'}
      });
      
      // return the panel
      return ui.Panel({
        widgets: [colorBox, description],
        layout: ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal')
      });
};


//  Palette with the colors
var palette =['FF0000', '22ff00', '1500ff'];

// name of the legend
var names = ['Red','Green','Blue'];

// Add color and and names
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  legend.add(makeRow(palette[i], names[i]));
  }  

// add legend to map (alternatively you can also print the legend to the console)  
Map.add(legend);
```